# Solving the free particle problem in momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}$(Note: this question was asked before [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374047/solving-the-schrodinger-equation-for-a-free-particle-in-momentum-space) but I didn't follow the answer.)

For the free particle, Schrödinger's equation is given by
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\ket{\psi(t)} = \frac{P^2}{2m}\ket{\psi(t)}.$$

I would like to solve for the wave function in momentum space, i.e. $\psi(p,t) = \langle p\ket{\psi(t)}$. My first step was to try solve the eigenvalue problem
$$H\ket{E} = \frac{P^2}{2m}\ket{E} = E\ket{E}$$
in momentum space, which yields
$$ \frac{1}{2m}\bra{p}P^2\ket{E} = E\langle p\ket{E},\\\frac{p^2}{2m}\psi_E(p) = E\psi_E(p).$$
where $P\ket{p}=p\ket{p}$ and $\psi_E(p) = \langle p \ket{E}$.

I'm not entirely sure where to go from here to determine $E$ and $\psi_E(p)$. It seems like $E = p^2 / 2m$, but the fact that $p$ is a variable confuses me.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to look at this problem is to consider it in position space, and then transform the solution to it's momentum space representation. While this may seem like an unnecessary amount of work, it may illuminate to you the delta function solution in a different way. So, in position space we have

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=E\psi\:\:\:\xrightarrow{\kappa^2\:\equiv\:2mE/\hbar^2}\:\:\: \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=-\kappa^2\psi\:\:\:\rightarrow\:\:\:\psi(x)=Ae^{i\kappa x}+Be^{-i\kappa x}$$

Before casting this into its momentum space representation, recall the integral representation of the Dirac delta function (which can be arrived at by considering orthogonality of position or momentum eigenstates):

$$\delta(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int e^{ix(\alpha-\beta)/\hbar}dx.$$

Using the above, let's Fourier transform our solution to get its momentum representation:

$$\psi(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int\psi(x)e^{-ipx/\hbar}dx = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int e^{ix(\kappa-p/\hbar)}dx + \frac{B}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int e^{ix(-\kappa-p/\hbar)}dx\\ = \sqrt{2\pi\hbar}\Big[A\delta(\kappa-p/\hbar)+B\delta(-\kappa-p/\hbar)\Big].$$

Now stick in $\kappa = \sqrt{2mE}/\hbar$, and use the fact that $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$ and  $\:\delta(\alpha x) = \delta(x)/|\alpha|$ to rewrite this as

$$\psi(p) = \tilde{A}\delta(p-\sqrt{2mE}) + \tilde{B}\delta(p+\sqrt{2mE}),$$

where I've collected constants and called them $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{B}$ for simplicity of the final solution. Obviously this is more work than noticing the solution in momentum space corresponds to delta function behavior, but perhaps you'll find this route illuminating; or, if nothing else, a nice consistency check.

Comment: Thanks, this is really neat! I am specifically interested in solving Schrödinger's equation in momentum space, but this is a useful way to check.

Answer (score 2):

You get the solution of
$$ \frac{p^2}{2m}\psi_E(p) = E\psi_E(p) $$
as follows

$$ \left(\frac{p^2}{2m}-E \right)\psi_E(p) = 0 $$

For this equation to hold it must be either $\frac{p^2}{2m}-E = 0$ or $\psi_E(p) = 0$.
That means for every $p$ except for $p=\pm\sqrt{2mE}$ it must be $\psi_E(p) = 0$.
Only for $p=\sqrt{2mE}$ and $p=-\sqrt{2mE}$ it is allowed that $\psi_E(p)$ is non-zero.

So the most general solution to all this is (using the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function))

$$ \psi_E(p) = A \delta(p-\sqrt{2mE}) + B \delta(p+\sqrt{2mE})$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: While I'm familiar with the Dirac delta, it's unclear to me how exactly the second equation follows from the first.

Comment: @J-J I've added more detailed explanation for that.

Comment: $E = \hbar^2 k^2 /2m $ ?

Comment: That makes some sense. One problem: $p = \pm\sqrt{2mE}$, so I guess $\psi_E(p) =  A\delta(p - \sqrt{2mE}) + B\delta(p + \sqrt{2mE})$?

Comment: @J-J Yes, you are right. I forgot this bit.

Comment: I don't see how you can make the jump to the Dirac delta function from what you have given so far. All I can tell is that your wavefunction is a piecewise function.

Comment: @AaronStevens Not just piecewise. $\psi(p)$ needs to be zero nearly everywhere,
except at $p=\pm\sqrt{2mE}$.

Comment: Right, the Dirac delta function isn't the only thing that has that property. I'm not saying the conclusion is wrong, I'm saying so far the jump to it is not justified based on those points alone

Comment: I think it can be shown that the Dirac delta is the only function in this case which normalises to $\delta(0)$, but I'm not sure if there is another function (square root of Dirac delta?) which normalises to unity.

Comment: @J-J That's what I'm trying to say. The answer has not given all the necessary points to say it's the Dirac delta function.